# i want to send message without Enterkey in node.js

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, bluetooth

```
AndroidPhone---------Raspberry Pi ------------Arduino
(server)              (server)               (bluetooth)
                    (bluetooth)
```

Now i can send `message(0or1)` from Android to Raspberry Pi by app
and i want to send this message to Arduino

However, when i play this code, message is not sent by bluetooth.
I think (stdin.process.on) is need input by enter.
but i cant. please help me

```js
if (req.payload.toString() === '0') {
  console.log('0');
  process.stdin.on('data', function(data) {
    var buf1 = Buffer.from(data);
    serial.write(buf1,fuction(err, bytesWritten) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    });
  };
  serial.on('data',function(data){ console.log('Received'+data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code was copied and pasted, you should fix that misspelled "`fuction`" on line 5 first.

Edit:

> i want to know how to use stdin.on without console input

Sorry, I don't know much about messaging between devices but process.stdin is meant specifically to *read standard input*, which means either console input or messages piped to your node process from another process' stdout.

Comment: that is my mistake,  that is not problem. i want to know how to use stdin.on without console input